# What is the meaning of the phrase ‘in timely fashion’?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> It was very disturbing to learn that Google will not open source Android 3.0 **in timely fashion**.

What is the meaning of *in timely fashion*?

Comment: Another interesting thing about this quote: I didn't know "open source" could be a verb.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The phrase *in timely fashion* means *quickly*, *promptly*, *within a reasonable time frame*. One might also hear *in a timely manner*, which has the same meaning.

For further reference, here are the relevant definitions of [*timely*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1298904#m_en_us1298904) and [*fashion*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1246345#m_en_us1246345) according to NOAD:

> **timely** done or occurring at a favorable or useful time; opportune
>
> **fashion** a manner of doing something

Answer (score 14):

Basically, it means "quickly enough" or "on time".

> **[timely](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timely)**: 1. coming early or at the right time; 
>   2: appropriate or adapted to the times or the occasion

> **[fashion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fashion)**: 2b. mode of action or operation

Note that I usually hear/see this phrase with an article:

> You need to pay your bills **in *a* timely fashion** if you want your credit score to improve.

Omitting the article makes it sound a little awkward, but not necessarily incorrect.

Comment: Actually, I think the article makes it rather awkward. For me, it's either *in timely fashion* or *in a timely manner*.

Comment: Just for what it may be worth, in legal paperwork it's fairly common to see phrases like "timely filed" instead of "filed in a timely manner." I found it a bit jarring at first, but "timely" *is* constructed as an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Yes, I've seen that too, and it still jars for me - I understand the need to reduce "in a timely fashion" given how often it crops up in legal contexts, but personally I'd prefer "on time"! @Martha: +1 for it sounding better with an article.

Comment: According to Google, "in a timely fashion" is 8x more common than "in timely fashion" - and to me it sounds strange without the article.

Comment: Lawyers sometimes use *timeously* for this, to reduce the number of words. (That few people understand it is another advantage.)

Comment: @TimLymington, *timeously* sounds like a portmanteau of *timidly* and *piteously*. It doesn't sound like it has anything to do with time.

Comment: @Martha: You're right about the way it sounds: see my second sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It means “as quickly as is reasonable in a particular situation”.