# Adverbial form of "timely"

Tags: parts-of-speech

The following sentence seems incorrect to me, because the adjective *timely* is being used as an adverb:

> Payments not received **timely** will be returned and additional interest
>   will be due.

That said, does *timely* even have an adverbial form? *Timelyly?*

Comment: I don't think there's an adverbial form based on **time** - we use the word **promptly**.

Comment: "Does *timely* even have an adverbial form? *Timelyly*?" Well ... it does now ...

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18635/8019 ( *in timely fashion*)

Comment: My spelling teacher would probably have said *timely* becomes *timelily*.  Just as *happy* becomes *happily* and so on.

Comment: @GEdgar of course. Thanks for the clarification (that should have been obvious). I think we've collectively created a new adverb

Comment: @GEdgar Usually there is an exception made for adjectives ending in "ly": bodily, lovely, worldly, etc., do not have adverb forms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*On time* is surely the adverbial phrase that would be used in most cases. John Lawler would doubtless say that striving for a single related adverb (central though this usage would be in this case) is not a wise use of time.

Comment: I was pleasantly impressed to read all the great suggestions—promptly, timeously, punctually; even the original timely. But I think this one best captures the notion of a strict deadline for those payments. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8):

You could use "[timeously](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/timeous)". The word is often used in formal documents in Scotland, but is obscure in the rest of the Anglosphere.

Comment: It takes four syllables to say this, right?

Comment: @EricNelson: Yes, four syllables. But it takes six to say "in a timely manner" by my count.

Comment: @EricNelson Actually it's [three syllables](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/timeously). It's not *that* obscure, I've read it and heard it here in Australia.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *[timely](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timely)* as an adverb to mean "in time", though this is not so common.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

> Payments not received punctually will be returned...

Comment: Payments not received on time...